# Why isn't my piped grep working?

Tags: c, shell, pipe, stdin

I've written my own shell in C, and when I run `ls | grep .c`, I get nothing. Although unpiped commands are working fine, like `ls`. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "shell.h"
#include "builtins.h"
#include "makeargv.h"



void shell() 
{
    pid_t   shell_pid;
    int     i;
    int     flag = 1;
    int     argc0;
    int     argc1;
    int     fdl[2];
    int     fdr[2];
    size_t  input_size;
    char    cwd[128];   //this is being toggled
    char    *delim0;
    char    *delim1;
    char    *lastarg;
    char    *input;
    char    *debugdescriptor;
    char    **argvp;
    char    **firstargs;

    shell_pid = getpid();
    do
    {
        // Retrieve PID & CWD of the parent process. 
        getcwd(cwd, (128 * sizeof(char)));  
        printf("{%i}%s$ ", shell_pid, cwd);         

        // Retrieve input from stdin.
        input = NULL;
        input_size = 0;
        getline(&input, &input_size, stdin);

        //seperates the input into pipe-delimited arguments("tokens")
        delim1 = "|\n";
        argc1 = makeargv(input, delim1, &argvp);

        //got some debugging tools here
        //debugdescriptor = "PIPE-SEPERATED";
        //debug_args(&argvp, &argc1, debugdescriptor);


        //check for quit and cd first
        delim0 = " ";
        argc0 = makeargv(argvp[0], delim0, &firstargs);
        //more debugging tools here
        //debugdescriptor = "FIRST ARGS";
        //debug_args(&firstargs, &argc0, debugdescriptor);
        //exit
        if((i = strcmp(firstargs[0],"exit")) == 0 || (i = strcmp(firstargs[0],"quit")) == 0)
        {
            printf("===========SHELL TERMINATED==============\n\n");
            flag = 0;
        }
        //cd
        else if((i = strcmp(firstargs[0],"cd")) == 0)
        {
            chdir(firstargs[1]);
        }

        else // Create a child process to handle user input.
        {
            char **thisarg;
            int childlayer = 0;
            pid_t pid = fork();
            wait(0);
            if(pid == 0)
                childlayer++;               
            int tokens = argc1 - 1;
            if(argc1 == 1 && pid == 0)
            {
                makeargv(argvp[tokens], delim0, &thisarg);
                execvp(thisarg[0], thisarg);
            }
            else //more than 1 arguement, (has pipes)
            {
                while(pid == 0 && childlayer < argc1){
                    if(childlayer == 1){ //rightmost
                        pipe(fdl);
                        pid = fork();
                        wait(0);
                        if(pid == 0)
                            childlayer++;
                        if(pid > 0){
                            close(fdl[1]);
                            dup2(fdl[0], STDIN_FILENO); //sets the final output to write to STDIN
                            execute(childlayer, argc1, &argvp);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(childlayer > 1 && childlayer < argc1-1){ //middle args
                        pipe(fdr);
                        fdr[1] = fdl[1];
                        fdr[0] = fdl[0];

                        dup2(fdr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

                        pipe(fdl);
                        pid = fork();
                        wait(0);
                        if(pid == 0)
                            childlayer++;
                        if(pid > 0){
                            close(fdl[1]);
                            dup2(fdl[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                            execute(childlayer, argc1, &argvp);
                        }
                    }
                    else{ //leftmost
                        pipe(fdr);
                        fdr[0] = fdl[0];
                        fdr[1] = fdl[1];
                        close(fdr[0]);
                        dup2(fdr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                        execute(childlayer, argc1, &argvp);
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    }while(flag == 1);  
}
```

I think I may be getting stuck in a child process when I use the pipes, but I haven't been able to see where. Thanks.

Comment: Well first of all it should be `ls | grep \.c` or it will match a file named `helloc`, you should make it `ls | grep \.c$` so it won't match `hello.c.backup`.

Comment: Such problems are almost always due to not `close()`ing the pipes as appropriate.  If a process has both ends of a pipe open and is waiting for an EOF on that pipe, it will never come (pipe waits for last writer to close the pipe first).

Comment: @PlasmaPower :why should it it be \.c? is the backslash an escape character for the dot? Please elaborate on what you mean, I'm interested in understanding further.

Comment: grep will treat a dot as a wildcard unless it is escaped with a backslash.  The dollar is required to anchor the regex so that it will not match a .c in the middle of the filename

Comment: By "anchor the regex" I assume you mean that it has to be by itself?
so for example .csv wouldn't be a match?

Comment: Yes, the $ is a zero-width lookahead assertion that only matches at the end of line.  The example above was preventing a match on `hello.c.backup`, but `hello.csv` is also prevented.  It has nothing to do with the question, and in fact, for all we know, you were actually looking for all filenames with some character followed by a `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly failing to close all your file descriptors.  One source of such an error is your `dup2` calls.

After:

```
dup2(fdr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
```

you should call

```
close(fdr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you `wait(0)` immediately after `fork()`?  In the child, this will return immediately with an error, but in the parent, it will block until the child exits.  I'm having a hard time following how the pipeline is established because each child is forking off the next child in the pipeline.  I'm guessing the `wait(0)` is creating a chicken-and-egg problem; the parent can't start until the child exits, but the child can't exit because it needs input from the parent.  Wouldn't it be simpler if the shell process just looped over the pipeline components and forked each one itself, and then waited for them all to finish?

Comment: I use the wait(0) so that the parent waits until the child is done executing before it continues. 
This shell is supposed to be able to handle an indefinite number of pipes. 
How my pipeline works is lets say I have "cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd 3 | cmd 4"   then it will fork once per command, and the lowest child will handle cmd1, writing the output of cmd1 to STDIN of the parent with execvp, which will end the child process. then immediately following, the waiting parent can execute the next command up the list(cmd2). The commands are pipe-seperated before any forking is done, so children can see them.

Comment: So, once we get into the `while(pid == 0 && childlayer < argc1)` loop, the first iteration goes into the the `childlayer == 1` case, which forks, waits for the child to exit, and then executes the rightmost command, with input from the pipe.  This implies that all of the output from the child must have been buffered in the pipe.  But if the child is backpressured because the pipe is full, it will not exit, so the parent will block in a deadlock.

Comment: You can still create a pipeline with an indefinite number of commands by having the shell process loop over the `argvp` array, creating pipes and forking children without calling `wait`.  Only when all of the children have been forked should the shell process call `wait` as many times as there are children.  In a normal shell, all of the children in a pipe have the shell as their parent process, not the command after them in the pipe.

Comment: I can see how this would work much better. As a follow-up question: when you have the parent process loop around and create a child process for each pipe-separated command, how can you be sure that they will finish in the correct order?

Comment: Why do you care about the order in which they finish?

Comment: if I have "ls | grep a" I would want ls to finish before grep executes, otherwise what is grep going to look in?

Am I looking at this entirely wrong?

Comment: Both processes will run concurrently, with the pipe passing chunks of the `ls` output to the `grep` input.  In general, you cannot have `ls` finish before `grep` starts because pipes can only buffer a small finite amount of data.  If `ls` tries to write some output into the pipe when it is full, it will be blocked until the reader makes some space by reading.  If the reader isn't even started until the writer is done, you will have a deadlock if the writer generates more output than the pipe can buffer.